# Breaking a crypted german recipe text

Tags: text, encryption

I've got the problem, that I have to solve a task where I have to decrypt a cook-recipe text-file. I do not have any information about the content, except that the title is in the first line. The recipe itself is in german.
I tried a few chifre's but nothing worked yet. I think it could be some kind of transformation block chiffre, where the text is splitted into different blocks, and those blocks are crypted with a secret key. Maybe you've got an idea, because unfortunately I am out of ideas:

```
HprTincw.Mn clnsli vc
rcean rhneettHhtden is
öretMnil ve egtanme nisirrt
n tMeesSemddmnicc ue
2set nlo ozefhn acf)nieg äantgefk
E iean emwglsh
etn ameemdun feDen es ei bl b e.ekvzbtzw Cn a nrres
r bret lnve fh. nk
efemceeKrrneu ee Ss Wm ffgewinera e
Bi e lMü tht leofü edeheihrän ei eRshe e oätmtrH esh
eihTittudelamanizgni aei aürä ente zanegt
nahce f ew ie enganT ebi.DTiuek lna e mntgnle,bs isca gör .
e glh ebsbnu cslhen eeee etähohsgdrnt
/e gsew0cagolfr.DRl unmp ctudfeBceheet e.MtnriredLnncierin dnp ce
ibmMlvrlgudeVif itaieicetce
Vdmsle g3w c g lnren asefsenZ ltn
elie fadnösnii teglnueelstElmhbrin
Dnco oieOeneteta0G )e fnmloleaieamOthnse
be hstaegsra.sBbei ohinBoecin a3i.ce
DHfp i iakirlg unoeke snZtnfdnft:2 cga,5 ene 1reee0 krtaZtesl,PiSl2E,1wi
eec:1gl1Eic efreAisceetrdBefz
Fdni a etereDsh enürüsgbudrfi eeerie.Desle gue iaweSehuü.DZtnmdmnrgrmtnKhkkru die,dnu htSui a5ntz e teegrrtne gzdcs g enwr reeas
rc hbvrseht
DTiecmth tu,adrhs enuafrbhtAbslenmlu cke.As3dTi a4mleRe mni ln i ofee ui kl gtelg
i eole g he eeui odün
Dsgli c she ietugtesElmhbrin o eihTi t3 lnRl onudr balieofeh.
nknrZpu reendVrfneen na iieicetce
afnren(rUri:e 8rd.DZpohssagnemwe e an i scihrvrsth aakc dnrezeaknseeEw5m an e eoafnmtBpp etnces atls.
aeü eeg5ghahe0gieh, ülH,8Zc,es rnca s z ir is
Zmsrhn ib LMh h irefä,F üa ce
egSl malihsenggdfmnitnzndu f u edei aufrrafstn uumtiaen eoeiaOhs
ehtesa
eiilä eün u lrf athnu e3 neeeeZlnanb(te
eTlre VfnZr.aethcndrn b e.nrcee5aof aelnpc eofgr eugdfmglsh
Beh /h 1a oc n ngl,sic ö Dchegtc bt b.nzue abehtla
trHi0ln0zlW u .oh1e,eEsuteE, ,ldbl fsh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a classical cypher of some sort, since it still appears to have words and spaces in it.  It has some extra complication in that digits and punctuation, `.:,)/`, appear to be part of the cypher alphabet.

Start by trying a Caesar shift.  After that look at an extended monoalphabetic substitution cypher.  If it is a recipe then you have some probable words, the German equivalents of "Ingredients", "boil", "slice", "kg", "grammes" etc.  Expected letter frequencies are a great help with monoalphabetic cyphers.

If it is not monoalphabetic, then it is likely a [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).  There are possible techniques there, but they are more complex.

My guess is that it is probably monoalphabetic, extended with additional characters.

---

**ETA:** Let's assume it is a transposition cypher.  The letters are correct, but not in the right order.  Start by assuming that the newlines are in the correct place.  We can change that assumption later if it doesn't work out.

The First line is "HprTincw.Mn clnsli vc"  That has two spaces, hence three words.  Presumably the words start with the capital letters: H, T, M and are likely to form the title: "Hot Toasted Muffins." or whatever the recipe is.  The position of the full stop gives us a clue as to where the end character is swapped to.

We now have a problem, there look like too few vowels to make three words.  Perhaps we need to include the end-of-line characters in our transposition?  The second line, "rcean rhneettHhtden is" has a lot more vowels, so the period is probably long enough to include some or all of it.

Proceed along those lines.  Once you have worked out some of the swaps, and the period of the swaps it will become easier to decode the rest.  Capital letters will nearly always follow a space or a newline.  Punctuation will often precede a space or a newline.  Numbers may indicate elements of a numbered list, or possibly quantities: "grammes".

A simple transposition can easily be tested for, look at every 2nd, 3rd 4th etc. character.  A permuted transposition is more difficult.

Comment: I am pretty sure, its not that one. The problem is, that there are one and two letter words. And in the german vocabulary aren't any one letter words. And only a few two letters.

Comment: Perhaps space is included in the substitution, so space actually represents a letter, and some other symbol represents a space.  Letter frequency tables might tell you.  In English text, space is the most frequent character, followed by 'e'.  I am not sure where space comes in the German frequency tables.

Comment: I tried it out, but that totally doesn't work. I think its some kind of transpositioning cipher (you know that one with the matrix). Because, the anlysis of the letter amounts says, its usual german. So the letters are not changed, they are just repositioned. Probably with a keyword or something. So it wont be this one :/

Comment: No update yet...I am still trying to search for those words but it just doesn't work.